# diagonal matrix with $k$ 1's and $n-k$ 0's

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is from an old qualifying exam.

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ and let $P$ be a projection on $V$ with
$\dim(P(V))=k$. Prove that there is an ordered basis for $V$ such that the matrix representation of $P$ with respect to this basis is a diagonal matrix with $k$ $1$'s and $n-k$ $0$'s on the diagonal.

My solution: Since $P$ is a projection, I can show that the only eigenvalues of 
$P$ are $0$ and $1$. Since $\operatorname{rank}(P)=k$ we have  $\operatorname{nullity}(P)=n-k$. And so the characteristic polynomial of $P$ is $f(x)=x^{n-k}(x-1)^{k}$ <---( Can I immediately say this 
or do I have to prove this fact???). The minimal polynomial $p(x)$ of $P$ must divide $x^2-x$ (because $x^2-x$ annihilates $P$). And so by Cayley Hamilton we must have that $p(x)=x(x-1)$. since $p(x)$ factors completely into distinct linear factors, we must have that $P$ is diagonalizable. And so there exits a basis in which the matrix representation has the desired form.

Is this a good solution?. Is there anything I have to prove more or be more clear :).

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: How are you defining "projection"?  By one frequently seen definition, to say that $P$ is a projection means simply that $P^2=P$.  That tells you the minimal polynomial divides $p(x)=x^2-x$ right away.

Comment: If $P^2=P$ then $P$ is said to be a projection.

Comment: So that gets you your statement about the minimal polynomial a lot faster.

Comment: Oh I see. Since the two characteristic values are $0$ and $1$ and since $p$ divides $x^2-x$ we must get $p(x)=x(x-1)$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What I meant was that if $P^2=P$ then $P^2-P=0$, so $P$ is a zero of the polynomial $p(P)=P^2-P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear.

1. **"I can show that the only eigenvalues of $P$ are $0$ and $1$."** Taking it literally, it means if $P$ has *some* eigenvalues, they must be either $0$ or $1$. Note that this is different from saying that *"$P$ has $n$ eigenvalues and all of them are either $0$ or $1$."* You see, when the field is not algebraically closed (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$), some matrices may not even possess a single eigenvalue.
2. **"And so by Cayley Hamilton ... ."** I don't see how Cayley-Hamilton theorem is relevant here. C-H thm says that the minimal polynomial must divide the characteristic polynomial, but here you first establish that $x^2-x$ is an annihilating polynomial, and then argue that the minimal polynomial must divide $x^2-x$. The characteristic polynomial is not used at all.
3. **"... we must have that p(x)=x(x−1)."** Why? $I$ and $0$ are projections, but their minimal polynomials are not $x(x−1)$.

On the whole, I think that the arguments you have shown look quite good. However, since the essential step that $P$ has $n$ eigenvalues in $\{0,1\}$ is not shown, I am not sure if you really have a correct proof.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well the first part of the question (which I didn't write here) was to show hat if $P$ is projection then the eigenvalues of $P$ are either $0$ or $1$. So I assumed that I somehow needed to use this fact in proving this. I used C-H in trying to show that $p$ must have the same roots as that of $f$.